Strapi work fine in my local system but when i deploy on my dev server its show this error
enter image description hereI'm encountering an issue when trying to access my URL on the development server. The following error occurs:
[Describe the specific error message here]
This functionality works correctly on my local machine but fails on the development server. I've attempted several solutions without success. Could someone please assist me in resolving this issue?
go this image

Post stack traces as text. That goes for code too. It also looks like you didn't anticipate the question being visible immediately.

The OP had issue regarding Strapi error The hook ContentReleases/pages/ReleaseDetails/add-locale-in-releases is not defined.
I had the same issue today and solved it by updating all strapi packages in package.json to newest version 4.23.0
"dependencies": {
        "@strapi/plugin-cloud": "4.23.0",
        "@strapi/plugin-i18n": "4.23.0",
        "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "4.23.0",
        "@strapi/provider-upload-aws-s3": "4.23.0",
        "@strapi/strapi": "4.23.0",
        "better-sqlite3": "8.6.0",
        ...

Hope this helps.
